# detach or remove after using replaceWith , but make it toggle

Tags: jquery

on click , after replacing the div with the ul li , how can i remove when i click button again , and repeat process on each click ? I need to keep original ul li in the DOM , so can not append , need to clone

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#button").toggleClass("newClass");
  $("div").replaceWith($("ul li"));
  if ($("#button").text() == "ADD UL LI TO DIV") {
    $("#button").text("REMOVE DIV CONTENT");
  } else {
    $("#button").text("ADD UL LI TO DIV");
  }
});
```

```css
#button {
  cursor: pointer
}

#button {
  background: red
}

#button.newClass {
  background: green
}

ul {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<span id="button">ADD UL LI TO DIV</span>
<div></div>
```

Comment: you want to toggle between the div and ul?

Comment: no , i want to clone the "li" , inside the "ul" , and append to a div , then toggle to show/hide the div with the ul li content

Comment: Post the whole example here, not at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: Why don't you hide and show things, instead of adding and removing them?

Comment: added whole example , i need to append and detach or remove on toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function f1() {
  $("ul").clone().appendTo("div");
  $("div ul").css("display", "block");
  $("#button").addClass("newClass").text("REMOVE DIV CONTENT");
  $(this).one("click", f2);
}

function f2() {
  $("div").empty();
  $("#button").removeClass("newClass").text("ADD UL LI TO DIV");
  $(this).one("click", f1);
}
$("#button").one("click", f1);
```

```css
#button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
}

#button.newClass {
  background: green
}

ul {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<span id="button">ADD UL LI TO DIV</span>
<div></div>
```

I believe this is what you need.